# How to render a file which is in an included engine in Rails 4.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-engines

In my Rails 4.2 app which consists of a few Rails engines, there is a need for  engine `itemlized_spendingx` to render a file in engine `biz_workflowx` with ajax call. The engine `biz_workflowx` is included in `itemlized_spendingx`'s application controller like this :

```
  module ItemlizedSpendingx

    class ApplicationController < ::ApplicationController

        include BizWorkflowx::WfHelper

    end
  end
```

In `BizWorkflowx::WfHelper`, there is a action `event_action` defined and it is called ajax with `link_to` from index view in engine `itemlized_spendingx`. Here is the `event_action.js.erb` responding to ajax call

```
$("#newworkflow .modal-content").html('<%= j render(:file => "biz_workflowx/application/event_action.html.erb") %>');
$("#newworkflow").modal();
```

The purpose of the `evant_action.js.erb` above is to popup a view of `event_action.html.erb` (both event_action.js.erb and event_action.html.erb reside in same subdir under biz_workflowx/app/views/application/) with Bootstrap modal. The problem I am having is that `render(:file => ..)` raises error of `template missing` even though the `File.file?('biz_workflows/app/views/application/event_action.html.erb`) returns `true` in `ActionView resolver`.

It seems that the `render` is really having hard time to locate `event_action.html.erb` even though `File.file?` sees it. How to make the renderer see it?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the `event_action.js.erb` that works:

```
$("#newworkflow .modal-content").html('<%= j render(:file => "/application/event_action.html.erb") %>');
$("#newworkflow").modal();
```

After removing the `biz_workflowx`, then the view template is found. It seems that the Rails view resolves the view template in a relative path and treats `event_action.html.erb` under the scope of `itemlized_spendingx`.